# Why are there two Cookie classes in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

Why are there two different, yet extremely similar classes in Symfony to represent a browser Cookie?

`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie` and `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand what Symfony components are.

> Symfony Components implement common features needed to develop websites. They are the foundation of the Symfony full-stack framework, but **they can also be used standalone even if you don't use the framework as they don't have any mandatory dependencies**.

They don't have any external dependencies, meaning that any dependency will be bundled with the component.

`HttpFoundation\Cookie` is a Cookie class used by the `HttpFoundation` component. And `BrowserKit\Cookie` is a class used by the `BrowserKit` component. They are small bundled dependencies of each of the components.  You should use the component, not an individual class inside it.

The purpose of these two components are

- **BrowserKit**    Simulates the behavior of a web browser.
- **HttpFoundation**    Defines an object-oriented layer for the HTTP specification.

Decide which components to use according to your scenario.